# How to write short PHP functions that work together

Tags: php, encapsulation

I want to modularize functions, but this is not working...

```
class Review {
    public function show_report($db, $id){
        // Query the DB on $id
        $x = $this->get_survey($db, 1);
        $y = $this->get_survey($db, 2);
        // Use x and y to build a report
        return $a_report;
    }
    private function get_survey($db, $n){
        // Query the DB for a certain survey number
        if($n == 1){
            // Perform some logic
        } else {
            // Perform some other logic
        }
        return $a_survey;
    }
};
```

Using the class like this..

```
<?php
    include_once('api/Review.class.php');
    $r = new Review();
?>
<p>
<?php
    echo Review::show_report($db, $id);
?>
</p>
```

PHP throws this:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in Review.class.php
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your design pattern is good, you just have a syntax error.  You have missed the $ sign on your method calls in show_report(), it should look like this:

```
public function show_report($db, $id){
    // Query the DB on $id
    $x = $this->get_survey($db, 1);
    $y = $this->get_survey($db, 2);
    // Use x and y to build a report
    return $a_report;
}
```

Also, the semicolon at the end of the class is unnecessary.

Finally, as another person mentioned, you need to call show_report with parameters, like this:

```
echo $r->show_report($db, $id);
```

Comment: Now I am getting `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in Review.class.php on line 42`

Comment: Could you post your complete code since there are variables which aren't declared in your example code?

Comment: I tried to abstract away some of the details (it's a long file), in doing so I fudged on accuracy. My bad. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function `show_report($db, $id)` is the `this` pointer without the prefixing `$` sign which causes the syntax error. Additionally in the second part the function isn't called with parameters.
The function has to look like that:

```
public function show_report($db, $id){
    // Query the DB on $id
    $x = $this->get_survey($db, 1);
    $y = $this->get_survey($db, 2);
    // Use x and y to build a report
    return $a_report;
}
```

Comment: This was one of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $r->show_report;
```

In this example, you are attempting to call the function with no arguments. If this is really what you are doing, that would be at least one problem.

Instead, call the function with arguments:

```
echo $r->show_report('foo', 1);
```

Comment: This was right next to the root cause. I was calling show_report in a static context.

Comment: Ah, you didn't have the `echo Review::show_report($db, $id);` in your original post, or I would have mentioned also that yes, you need to do `echo $r->show_report($db, $id);` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I fixed all the syntax errors, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258788/1004107. This is the root of the issue I do believe:

```
<?php
    include_once('api/Review.class.php');
    $r = new Review();
?>
<p>
<?php
    echo Review::show_report($db, $id);
?>
</p>
```

Should be...

```
<?php
    include_once('api/Review.class.php');
    $r = new Review();
?>
<p>
<?php
    echo $r->show_report($db, $id);
?>
</p>
```

And this is do to static context? Please comment.